# Javascript Bitwise Op

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I was wondering if there's a way to find out if given binary pattern, two or more of the 1's are within another binary pattern. I say pattern because the actual value of it does not determine if one is within another.

For example,

```
0001 1110 0000 0000
0001 1111 0000 0000
--> true

0001 0000 1100 0000
0001 1111 0000 0000
--> false

0001 1100 0000 1000
0001 0000 0000 1111
--> true

0001 1000 1100 0000
0001 0000 0000 1111
--> false
```

I tried using variety of AND/OR/XOR/NOT but not sure how to do it.
Please help!

So the question about the data in question is like this:

```
const RANKS = [
  0b0000000001110001,
  0b0000001001000110,
  0b0001001100000100,
  0b0000000011011000,
];
```

I'm trying to loop over RANKS to see if it matches a pattern:

```
const PATTERNS = [
  0b0001111100000000,
  0b0000111110000000,
  0b0000011111000000,
];
```

Only 2 of the 1's from RANK has to "fit" in PATTERN to consider as true

Comment: Is data in array buffer or string?

Comment: How is 2nd example valid. Should it not be true

Comment: Does each array contain four elements? Can you include array representation of data at stacksnippets?

Comment: The second one is false because only 1 of the 1's fits the pattern to match

Comment: You can use `&` and then [count bits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sharesAtLeastTwoBits(x, y) {
  var a = x & y;
  if (!a) return false;
  while (!(a & 1)) a >>>= 1;
  return a != 1;
}

console.log(sharesAtLeastTwoBits(
  0b0001111000000000,
  0b0001111100000000
))

console.log(sharesAtLeastTwoBits(
  0b0001000011000000,
  0b0001111100000000
))

console.log(sharesAtLeastTwoBits(
  0b0001110000001000,
  0b0001000000001111
))

console.log(sharesAtLeastTwoBits(
  0b0001100011000000,
  0b0001000000001111
))
```

Use `&` to figure out which bits they have in common. If no bits are in common, `false`. If not, shift right till the lowest bit is at 0th position; if it is the only bit that is `1`, the whole number is `1`, so `false` again; otherwise true.

EDIT: andyg0808's answer is more general.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works perfectly. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If you `and` the two patterns together, you will get a pattern with bits set only in the positions where both patterns have a `1`. You can then use one of the algorithms for [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) to count the number of bits that are set. The simplest algorithm would be the following function `count`:

```js
function count(num) {
  var c = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    if (num & 1) {
      c++;
    }
    num = num >>> 1;
  }
  return c;
}
console.log(count(1)); /* 1 */
console.log(count(2)); /* 1 */
console.log(count(3)); /* 2 */
```

H/T to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/2243495) for the term *Hamming Weight*.

Comment: Thanks for providing another solution. This works as well.